# How should I increase version number for PHP REST APIs?

Tags: php, rest, api

I read about version format here: [Versioning](https://www.xmatters.com/integrations/blog-four-rest-api-versioning-strategies/)

It described version as: **MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH** (example: 1.12.3)

They have also written:

> Minor and Patch versions: These are **transparent** to the client and used
>   internally for backward-compatible updates.

To understand **transparent** thing, I read snailboat's answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17693/what-is-the-correct-interpretation-of-transparent):

Now, I have changed some code in my API to fix bugs and increase performance of client (android **app**). This also requires some changes on client side (some changes in app).

According to first link, if I have currently version **2.0.0**, I can update it to **2.0.1**. But they also stated that *"These are transparent to the client"* which means app **DOES NOT** need any changes (Did I understand that right? I'm not sure.)

But according to 2nd link, snailboat has quoted:

> "transparent to the **user**." In other words, the user enjoys the
>   benefits of a particular function without being aware of how it is
>   accomplished."

He emphasized on word user/customer rather than client. That means, **user** does not see any change, but does that also mean client **DOES NEED** some change?

So, I'm little confused and my question is: Is it possible to update my API from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 maintaining the transparency? If yes, who wouldn't be affected: User/Customer or Client (app)?

PS: I need to increase the version to support the older apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule of thumb for [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) I've learned from many different people:

1. Consumer needs to change implementation: **major version**
2. New features added, consumer doesn't need to change: **minor version**
3. Bugfixes, consumer doesn't need to change: **patch**

Now ofcourse this comes with some caveats, especially early in development where pretty much every change results in a major version. It's up to you when to release a 1.0.0 version. From that moment on however, you absolutely always stick to semantic versioning.

If I understood you correctly ("*This also requires some changes on client side*"), you need to bump to 3.0.0.

**EDIT**: see image below

**Transparancy**: using `/api/v2` is transparent to the consumer. He knows he's on major version 2 and that's all he needs to know. If you release a major version 3 and thus a `/api/v3`, he can decide whether to update or not.

Under the hood, ofcourse you're constantly updating and fixing the api. That's internal versioning and what I thought your question was about. Here you use semantic versioning. The consumer should only have to care about the major version.

[image]

Comment: If there are bug fixes and needs some change on apps, I shouldn't update the app code? In that way how will app access the new api version?

Comment: That's why you have version and (git) tags and releases right? You simply update the api. All the client has to know is that he is on major version 2. He doesn't care about the minor and patch versions. He wants the latest greatest in the current major version. In Radu's example: change the url to `http://api.com/api/2` for major version 2 and that's it. For a composer package, you simply `composer update` since the interface to the client hasn't been changed.

Comment: But why update the api url (latest) for client (app) even for some fixes and improvements? Your statements seem to me contradicting. We need to update the api url for major update?

Comment: Updated my question with a picture and some more explanation.

Comment: Okay. Does that mean I need to use only Major version INTEGER (e.g. /v2) in api url and that too when I have done all fixes and improvement and not when I have done a few fixes and improvements?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but the the api url only consists of the major version integer indeed. No matter how high the minor or patch integers are. `2.83.291` still means `/api/v2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171154/discussion-between-rahul-and-loek).

Answer (score 2):

You should update your internal api version to `2.0.1`, but this shouldn't be reflected in the way clients consume your API.

Let's assume you are storing the API version as part of the URL, something like this `http://api.com/api/2.0/`, when making patch changes you shouldn't change this to `http://api.com/api/2.0.1` as this would break transparency for the clients consuming the API.

If someone is using the API in a mobile app changes are needed in the source code to reflect the change, which is less than ideal.

When making changes to minor and/or major versions the changes should be reflected in the API versioning. 
This means that clients need to make changes to source code, but this is ok as changes in minor/major should be agreed by the consumers.

Note: you'll end up supporting multiple versions of your API `http://api.com/2.0` `http://api.com/2.1` and so on.

Comment: *update your internal api version to 2.0.1, but this shouldn't be reflected in the way clients consume your API* But the how will app access the the API 2.0.1? I mean without changing the request URI? (I'm including version in URI).

Comment: They will use 2.0.1 by default. They will be using 2.0 in the URL, they shouldn't specify the patch version in the API version. This means that anybody pointing to API 2.0 will actually get the latest 2.0.x. This is ok, because changing the patch version means total backwards compatibility and should only contain bug fixes. If you introduce new features then you should update the minor (or major) version.

Comment: All of this means I should write handling in my back end to support old and new apps equally until next minor/major release?

Comment: No. This means that all users are updated to the latest patch version without them doing anything. You'll need backend handling for minor/major releases, but you shouldn't need to do anything for patch releases.

Comment: Wait. If the users don't change their code and they use latest patch version, why did you say *but you shouldn't need to do anything for patch releases*. If users are not changing anything, I guess I WILL need some backend handling. For example: If a request format is changed, the how will user access the resources without correct request format? I'll need to modify that request parameters in the latest format.

Comment: The change you are talking about is not a change that should be reflected in the change of the patch version. What you are saying breaks backwards compatibility and that means that it should bump the minor (or major) version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171247/discussion-between-rahul-and-radu-di).